# Azure-Devops-Extension: Make group contribution optional for all Processes by default

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I am currently developing an Azure Devops Extension with a group contribution for work items: `ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-group`.
Unfortunately, I realized that this contribution is added to any Proccess of the organization the extension is installed to *by default*. Since we have multiple different projects using different processes within our organization, and this extension only aims to be used in one single project, I am looking for a setting that makes this contribution **disabled by default** for all processes (including the predefined processes which cannot be edited). I am aware that the group integration can be manually hidden in the page modifier in the process settings (for inherited processes) but I want this integration to be manually added and not added by default. Also some projects use the default processes which cannot be edited and therefore the group integration cannot be removed as far as I know. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find anything about that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can not configure extensions on process template level. Other than hiding/showing the contributions, that is. And if you are using base template, you can not do that, either.

However you could use feature flags for enabling/disabling contributions on collection or project level.
You can find an example [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample/blob/master/src/Samples/Feature/Feature.json).